# Unable to import entire xl sheet using datatable.import method

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

My xl file has got 5 sheets [Login,Equipment,MaintainPart, SerializedItem & Logout] .
When I try to import this xl file in QTP/UFT using 'datatable.import' method then it only import 1st two sheets [Login & Equipment] & skip rest. I am using Excel 2013. 
Check attached image for more details. [image]

If I am not wrong it should show respective sheet name in the run time datatable. But in this case it is showing 'global' & 'action1' as import sheet name.

Answer (score 3):

By default, QTP/UFT have two sheets: Global & Action1.
SO when you'll use "DataTable.Import" it will automatically use Global & Action1 sheets and will place your first two sheets data onto it.

Let's say you have four sheets (*sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4*) and you want to import all the sheets, do something like this.

```
Dim fname, sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4
fName = "C:\Users\aa24800\Desktop\Test.xlsx"
sheet1 = "Sheet1"
sheet2 = "Sheet2"
sheet3 = "Sheet3"
sheet4 = "Sheet4"

'ADDING THE SHEETS TO DATATABLE (YOU CAN GIVE YOUR OWN NAME TO SHEETS)
DataTable.AddSheet sheet1
DataTable.AddSheet sheet2
DataTable.AddSheet sheet3
DataTable.AddSheet sheet4

'IMPORTING THE SHEETS TO DATATABLE
DataTable.ImportSheet fname, sheet1, sheet1
DataTable.ImportSheet fname, sheet2, sheet2
DataTable.ImportSheet fname, sheet3, sheet3
DataTable.ImportSheet fname, sheet4, sheet4
```

This way you'll get all your sheets in QTP/UFT.

[image]